# remove_ending vs keep_before in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

Is there a difference between the two built-ins, remove_ending and keep_before?

https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_remove_ending

https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_keep_before

Answer (score 0):

- remove_ending doesn't support regex, keep_before does.
- remove_ending will remove only the last match if there are multiple, and leave the others. So 'ABC22'?remove_ending('2') would become 'ABC2'.
  keep_before stops at the first match, so 'ABC22'?keep_before('2') would become 'ABC'